# How to convert English input layout to Persian(farsi)

Tags: javascript, angular, farsi

Suppose we have a search input field. and our users have two keyboard layout (En)(Fa):

sometimes users forget to change keyboard layout,
so instead of => **"سلام"**
input => **"sghl"**.

in this case, google almost detects the problem, and offer proper results.

**first**, I don't know what is this algorithm's name.
i search and found "Google Instant’s Autocomplete" in https://searchengineland.com/how-google-instant-autocomplete-suggestions-work-62592, but it is not my case,
check my screenshot: https://imggmi.com/full/2019/4/12/b411bcbe08dcd1eb02a46487e836a0b2-full.png.html i write "لخخلمث" instead of "google" but google offer proper result.

**second and main problem**, i found "convert-layout" in https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-layout, it's what i need. it's 'fromEn()' function change wrong input to correct one,

as my project is angular, i write:

```
declare var require:any;
var fa = require('convert-layout/fa.js');
let correct = fa.fromEn('sghl');
```

i expect to get "سلام", but it's return "س`شا" and it's not correct.
i checked source in https://github.com/ai/convert-layout/blob/master/fa.json and map is correct:

"s": "س",
"g": "ل",
"h": "ا",
"l": "م",

what is the problem?

simple editable address: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnnsg9

Comment: I wouldn't assume google has a specific algorithm for that, instead it seems plausible to me that they would notice most people searching for "sghl" won't follow any link from the results and search for "سلام" just after

Comment: please screenshot: https://imggmi.com/full/2019/4/12/b411bcbe08dcd1eb02a46487e836a0b2-full.png.html

Answer (score 3):

I've written this for my personal use. Feel free to modify it to your needs (you can find it as a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/alijsh/daf08baf6e9f4b708d655965ddb4be70)):

```js
function fixPersian(input) {
  var letters = {
    'q': 'ض',
    'w': 'ص',
    'e': 'ث',
    'r': 'ق',
    't': 'ف',
    'y': 'غ',
    'u': 'ع',
    'i': 'ه',
    'o': 'خ',
    'p': 'ح',
    '[': 'ج',
    ']': 'چ',
    'a': 'ش',
    's': 'س',
    'd': 'ی',
    'f': 'ب',
    'g': 'ل',
    'h': 'ا',
    'j': 'ت',
    'k': 'ن',
    'l': 'م',
    ';': 'ک',
    '\'': 'گ',
    'z': 'ظ',
    'x': 'ط',
    'c': 'ز',
    'v': 'ر',
    'b': 'ذ',
    'n': 'د',
    'm': 'پ',
    ',': 'و',
    'C': 'ژ',
    'H': 'آ',
    'A': 'ؤ',
    'S': 'ئ',
    'G': 'أ',
    'L': '«',
    'K': '»'
  };

  var output = '';

  for (var i = 0, il = input.length; i < il; i++) {
    output += letters[input.charAt(i)] || input.charAt(i);
  }

  return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use any library for doing that. You can write a simple javascript function and pass the wrong word to it(`sghl` in your case for example). This function can be something like this:

```
function correctWord(input) {
   var fa = require('convert-layout/fa.json');
   var result = '';
   var charArray = input.split('');
   for (let ch of charArray) {
      result += fa[ch];
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you @hamed but it's supports multi languages, from and to, uppeercase and ..., i want to find problem, anyway ممنون.

Comment: it's useful. (;